# Transition to a section of page in Angular 2 component

Tags: angular

Is it possible to switch to a particular section of a page in an Angular 2 app across components (maybe using Routing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fragment` parameter of `routerLink` and `router.navigate`.
See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier
The fragment allows to jump to elements with matching ids.

> In URIs for MIME text/html pages such as http://www.example.org/foo.html#bar the fragment refers to the element with id="bar".

You can have fragment-only links also without using the router.